# MVC3 razor remote validation - Controller argument is always empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

I can call the controller but the argument (string) is always null.

All the examples I have found name the controller argument the same as the property we are validating remotely, sounds good/easy, but if you look at fiddler what is really being passed in is the name attribute from the input statement. Well that is problematic in that it is a subscripted name something like `Person.EMailAddresses[0].Address`, well I can't name my controller parameter like that.

So how do I get around this? There must be a way to specify the controllers parameter name in the `remote()` attribute?

Comment: Please supply Route and Controller method code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done using the default RemoteAttribute.  [This is a link](http://forums.asp.net/post/4189265.aspx) to an example I posted of a reusable remote validation attribute, where you can specify the name of the controller, action and the name of the variable used to pass the value to the action.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am going to give that a try now.

Comment: Couple of problems, can not find ControllerSessionState.   Second the RemoteReusableAttribute never gets called. The adapters.add("remoteval"... ) also never gets called.  However the RemoteReusableAttributeAdapter does get called when the form loads.